# How can I see all the 'npm WARN' that comes up after npm install?

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-modules

I want to see the warnings that comes up after npm install, but without calling npm install. Is there a command I can use for that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `npm install --dry-run` to

> report in the usual way what the install would have done without actually installing anything.
>   [Npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

You could also use `npm audit` for security warnings.
[Npm audit](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit)